# How to install a paid SSL (Comodo or Sectigo) to Harbor: Private Docker Registry?

Tags: docker, ssl, registry, harbor

I was trying to install `Harbor: Private Docker Registry` with Paid SSL from **Sectigo(Comodo)**.

But when I install, I can see it was successful in web page, but not in `docker login`.

When I tried to `docker login ~~~`, then it says 
`Error response from daemon: Get https://docker.siadev.kr/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

What I received from SSL provider are these.
`{domain}.crt`, `{domain}.key`, `AAACertificateServices.crt`, `AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt`, `COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt`, `COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt`, `SectigoRSAAddTrustCA.crt`, `SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt`, `rsa-dv.chain-bundle.pem`

And docker says it supports `ca.crt`, `{domain}.cert`, `{domain}.key`.

What crt files do I have to concat?

---

I placed those like,

`/etc/docker/certs.d/{domain}/{domain}.cert`
`/etc/docker/certs.d/{domain}/{domain}.key`
`/etc/docker/certs.d/{domain}/ca.crt`
.

If I try to login with ip or another domain, then it says `Error response from daemon: Get https://{domain}/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for {domain}, not {fake_domain}`.

So I assume that they are in the right place, and the problem is from wrong combine of `ca.crt`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's going to solve your problem but I think you should put your certificate in

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/$MY_REGISTR_DOMAIN:REGISTR_PORT/
```

folder. That's where I placed mine (they are self signed) and it works.